# Number of 10 digit numbers having digits 0,1,2 so that no two 0s are consecutive.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, contest-math

**Question : Find the number of 10 digit numbers having digits 0,1,2 so that no two 0s are consecutive.** (here a number cannot begin with 0)

And here's my attempt : Let $b_n$ denote the number of such numbers with length $n$ and ending with $1,2$ (here the leading digit cannot be $0$) and $a_n$ the number of numbers ending with $0$.
Let $c_n=a_n+b_n$, we want to find $c_{10}$.
Note that $$a_n=b_{n-1}$$ since the second last digit of this thing should be a $1$ or a $2$. Also, $b_n=b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}=c_{n-1}$. It suffices to find $b_{11}$ but $b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$ so it is easy to compute.

Note: I am not looking for the answer, just to check if my approach is correct and if better approaches exist

EDIT :  I guess this is a slightly less confusing way : denote by $a_n,b_n,c_n$ number of "numbers" of length $n$ ending with $0,1,2$ respectively, and $d_n=a_n+b_n+c_n$. Clearly, $b_n=c_n$ and $a_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}=2b_{n-1}$. Further $b_n=c_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}=d_{n-1}$. But $b_n=2b_{n-2}+2b_{n-1}$ which is easy to compute

Comment: Seems like the optimal approach to me, deriving a straight recurrence for the answer. Good job!

Comment: Your idea looks good, but I think you should justify the equations a bit more. Especially the equation $b_n=b_{n-1} + a_{n-1}$ is just thrown out there with no explanation.

Comment: oh if the thing ends with 1 or 2 then it doesn't matter what the second last digit is

Comment: @NimbuPani i think you should think over $b_n=2b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}$

Comment: @NimbuPani i did not understand what you are looking for . You say "But $b_n=2b_{n−2}+2b_{n−1}$ which is easy to compute"  , what does it mean ? Are you looking for something which is not easy to compute? or do you want more complex method ?

Comment: Sorry for no clarifying @Blubasaur. The problem asks us to find $d_{10}$ which can be done after getting the reccurence since $d_{10}=a_{10}+2b_{10}=2b_{9}+2b_{10}$ and given the base values, we can now compute this. That remark at the end was just me being lazy by not actually computing the answer

Comment: @NimbuPani Can you please look at my answer ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur I am sorry but i do not have the answer :( I understand the recurrence though ! Thanks for taking the time to respond !

Comment: @NimbuPani " I am sorry but i do not have the answer" , because of that , i wrote answer. Are not you looking for $a_{10}$ ? there are $18272$ numbers of length $10$ that satisfy the condition

Comment: i thought you wanted to verify it @Bulbasaur
Anyways thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The recurrence for $b_n$ is $b_n = 2 c_{n-1} = 2b_{n-1} + 2a_{n-1} = 2b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}$ since given any number of length $n-1$ you can construct two numbers of length $n$ ending with $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Corrected the value.  It looks like i solved it for 9, rather than 10.

Answer (score 0):

The method here is to use something along the line of

```
1, 2  can have trailing 0, 1, 2   ie y
0     can have trailing    1, 2   ie x
```

If we suppose these numbers are x, y at some point, the next iteration gives 3x+2y, or

```
    1   2    3    4    5    6
x   0   2    6   14   34   82
y   2   6   14   34   82  198
```

This is an alternation of the silver series, with steps at 1+sqrt(2).

The series to extend is the even numbers, 2, 6,34,198  at the rate of t(n+1)=6t(n)-t(n-1).

The value of this is isoquad(6,5,2,6) = 6726.

The 6 comes from that this is t(n+1)=6t(n)-t(n-1). The 5 is the value to be found (col 5 = 10 digits), the 2, 6 are the leader values for t0 and t1 resp.

isoquad, written in rexx, is http://zabrodsky-rexx.byethost18.com/aat/a_memfis.html

The process is indeed correct, but we looked on the wrong cell for the answer.  The number presented is in the cell representing numbers starting with 1,2, and ending in a non-zero digit at 10 digits.

Repeating the calculation for 11 digits gives 16238.

Thanks to Barry Cipra for pointing the error exists.

Comment: Are you saying 6726 is the total count for the OP's problem? I get $2^8\cdot28=7168$ just for the count with two non-leading and non-adjacent $0$s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach: The number of ways you can pick where to put $k$ $0$'s with none at the beginning and none adjacent, is $10-k\choose k$.  This comes from stars-and-bars counting of nonnegative solutions to $(x_1+1)+(x_2+1)+\cdots+(x_k+1)+x_{k+1}=10-k$. So a workable formula is

$$2^{10}{10\choose0}+2^9{9\choose1}+2^8{8\choose2}+2^7{7\choose3}+2^6{6\choose4}+2^5{5\choose5}$$

This easily generalizes to $n$-digit numbers; whether it's better than a recursive approach is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

According to comment given by OP , he is asking to find the value of $a_{10}$ , but as he said , it is lazy to calculate this value. So , acccording to this reply , i assume that OP understand that how $a_n=2a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$ is obtained where $a_0=1,a_1=2 ,a_2=6$ .

Now, i will compute the value of $a_{10}$ using generating functions to make it easy for OP.

$\color{green}{\text{1.Step-)}}$ Lets define an ordinary generating function ,say $A(x)$, then $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$

$\color{green}{\text{2.Step-)}}$ Multiply each term in this recurrence relation by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and try to write this recurrence relation in terms of $A(x)$.

$\color{green}{\text{3.Step-)}}$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n-2}x^n$

$\color{green}{\text{4.Step-)}}$ Lets make a change in the bases to make it easy such that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n-2}x^n \color{red}{\rightarrow }\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+2}x^n=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}x^n+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}x^n$$

$\color{green}{\text{5.Step-)}}$ Lets check over each terms such that

- $2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}x^n =2A(x)$
- $2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}x^n= 2\frac{A(x)-1}{x}=\frac{2A(x)-2}{x}$
- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+2}x^n = \frac{A(x) -a_1x-1}{x^2}$ where $a_1 =2$ ,so it is equal to $\frac{A(x) -2x-1}{x^2}$

Now we obtain that $$\frac{A(x) -2x-1}{x^2} =\frac{2A(x)-2}{x} + 2A(x) $$

By solving the equation , $$A(x) = \frac{1}{1-2x-2x^2}$$

We wrote our recurrence realiton in terms of series , so lets *[CALCULATE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%29%2F%281-2x-2x%5E2%29)* it using wolfram-alpha.

$$1+2x+6x^2 +16x^3 +44x^4 +120x^5 +...+6688x^9 +\color{blue}{18272}x^{10}+ 49920x^{11}+...$$

As you see , the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is $18,272$ , you can see the other values ,as well. For example , $a_{16}$is equal to coefficient of $x^{16}$ , so it is $7,598,336$